# How SpringMVC @SessionAttributes sends session object to JSP

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am learning SpringMVC framework and I have got the following example from [here](http://javabeat.net/spring-mvc-annotations/). Java Controller:

```
SessionController.java

package javabeat.net.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sessiontest")
@SessionAttributes("sessionValue")
public class SessionController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getForm(@RequestParam("param") String paramVal, ModelMap map){
        System.out.println("Param Value : " + paramVal);
        map.addAttribute("sessionValue", "Test Object");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

JSP page:

```
hello.jsp

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    String value = (String)session.getAttribute("sessionValue");
    out.print(value);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to understand the flow of the execution:

to the best of my knowledge, it assumes that in the execution flow the URL `/sessiontest?param=paramVal` is going to be hit first. Then `paramVal` is screened to the console. Then the collection `map` is enriched with the key-value pair `"sessionValue"/"Test Object"`.  Then `"hello"` is returned . So when `hello.jsp` is being hit, it retrieves the just added value, and the html body screens `Test Object`.

If my above interpretation is correct, I would like to know:

1) who is passing `ModelMap map` object to the method `getForm`?

2) what is the purpose of returning `hello` to nowhere?

3) how `session` object in the JSP is tied with the `ModelMap map` where the new key-value pair is being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'm not really good at explaining things since my words are clumsy. 
But here is the thing :

> 1) who is passing ModelMap map object to the method getForm?

Spring container generates this model object and (behind the scene) invokes it as the argument to the method , it's working just like JSP Implicit Objects (*`request`*, *`response`*, .etc) where JSP Container makes them available in each page and these objects can be called directly without being explicitly declared .

*`ModelMap`* is used to wrap some attributes (key & value) so that you can deliver these values to the *view* returned from the method. So later, you can access these values in the view via its corresponding keys.

> 2). what is the purpose of returning hello to nowhere?

*hello* is the view name (`hello.jsp`) forwarded from the method where you can access the previous wrapped attributes in the map

> 3) how session object in the JSP is tied with the ModelMap map where
>   the new key-value pair is being added?

Spring’s *`@SessionAttributes`* is used on a controller to designate which model attributes (think these attributes as keys &  values wrapped in the map) should be stored in a session.

In simple explanation : Since this controller is annotated with *`@SessionAttributes("sessionValue")`*  so whenever a map wrap a value mapped with a key of "*sessionValue*" then the value will be available in HttpSession.

So then later you access this session attribute via implicit  *`session`* object in your view.

*`String value = (String)session.getAttribute("sessionValue"); // gives you "Test Object"`*